# set a default in C#

Tags: c#

I try to set a default parameter in C#
So if there is no string in the QueryString it will use the Day of today

```
public int theDay
{
    get { return Convert.ToInt16(Request.QueryString["d"]); }
    set {

        if ( value <= 31 && value > 0 )
            {
                theDay = value;
            }
            else {
                theDay = DateTime.Now.Day;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Your property setter is calling itself recursively. Don't do that...

Comment: It does not recognize the value if null

Comment: I think that needs to go into a method, named such that it describes what it's doing. A property setter should have an expected behaviour in that it will set the property to the supplied value, without mangling it first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private int _theDay = DateTime.Now.Day;

public int TheDay
{
     get 
     {
         if(Request.QueryString["d"] != null) 
              _theDay =  Convert.ToInt16(Request.QueryString["d"]);             

         return _theDay; 
     }
     set 
     {

        if ( value <= 31 && value > 0 )
        {
            _theDay= value;
        }
        else 
        {
            _theDay= DateTime.Now.Day;
        }
    }
}
```

You need something like that for your case. If there is possibility value of QueryString["d"] > 31 or < 0, you should make this check in get too.